# HTML конвертация в iOS приложение

Tags: ipad, меню, конвертация, html, ios

Здравствуйте.

Срочно нужно создать приложение "электронное меню ресторана" для iPad. Функционал приложения небольшой, всего лишь меню. У меня имеется html-код данного меню, допустим, готовый. Как мне бесплатно конвертировать его в iOS приложение?

Программу не нужно публиковать в AppStore. Установлю через iTunes. Как это можно сделать?

Благодарю за время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 1):

Создайте UIWebView, зашейте в бандл HTML файл, и открывайте его в ней же.